# How do I use jQuery AJAX with PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Just getting a rather annoying issue at the moment, would be very happy if somebody could help.

I was watching this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TR0gkGbMwW0 and I decided to have a go and see if it worked. However, after I hit enter with the domain in the text field, nothing happens.

My HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>TestingPage</title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="userInput">
     What is the domain you would like to find the IP of? <input type="text" name="ip"        id="ipsearch"/>
     </div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#ipsearch').change(function() {
            $ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: process.php,
                data: 'ip=' + $('ipsearch').val(),
                success: function(msg) {
                    $('#userInput').html(msg);
                }
            });
        });
    }); //document.ready
</script>

</body>



</html>
```

My PHP code:

```
<?php
if ($_GET['ip']):
    $internetProtocol=gethostbyname($_GET['ip']);
    echo($internetProtocol);
endif;
?>
```

Comment: You have typos in your code. Always check your browser console for errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a couple of typos. You have:

```
$ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: process.php,
    data: 'ip=' + $('ipsearch').val(),
    success: function(msg) {
        $('#userInput').html(msg);
    }
});
```

But you need (see comments):

```
$.ajax({ // missing period ($ is jQuery, ajax() is the function)
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'process.php', // quotes around strings
    data: 'ip=' + $('#ipsearch').val(), // fix ID selector, missing '#'
    success: function (msg) {
        $('#userInput').html(msg);
    }
});
```

Also, you PHP code is, for lack of better term, ugly, and probably won't work. This:

```
<?php
if ($_GET['ip']):
    $internetProtocol=gethostbyname($_GET['ip']);
    echo($internetProtocol);
endif;
?>
```

Would be better as:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['ip'])) {
    $internetProtocol = gethostbyname($_GET['ip']);
    echo $internetProtocol;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing some ' '  and the value selector is wrong. to call ajax, you'll need to write

`$.ajax` instead of `$ajax`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#ipsearch').change(function() {
        $.ajax({   //<<< period between $ and ajax
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'process.php', // <<< missing ' ' 
            data: 'ip=' + $('#ipsearch').val(),  //<<< missing #
            success: function(msg) {
                $('#userInput').html(msg);
            }
        });
    });
}); //document.ready
```